# How to resolve "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, editor

I want to setup editor.js in my Django project but it's not working (I mean the text editor in not coming through)
Then I've tried in a simple HTML and JS file to check it but text editor is not coming in here too. I've run through the console and it's saying

> editor.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

"

I've followed the documentation to install this --

npm init -y
npm i @editorjs/editorjs --save-dev

Link for the guide: https://editorjs.io/getting-started

Here is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1> text editor </h1>
    <div id="editorjs"></div>
    <button> save </button>
    <script  src="editor.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my JS code

```js
import EditorJs from '@editorjs/editorjs';


const editor = new EditorJs({

});
```

Can you help me to solve this problem!! thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you not using Webpack (or similar builders) you cannot use `import` . You can just add

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>
```

to header and remove `import EditorJs from '@editorjs/editorjs';` line from JS code .
Or start using `Webpack` , here tutorial https://www.jamesbaltar.com/django-webpack

Answer (score 0):

Try to install package via yarn -> yarn add --dev @editorjs/editorjs
After that check all packages listed in your project if all that listed then your problem well solved i think so.